# Nodal Lines of the Eigenvalue problem $\Delta u=\lambda u$

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, symmetry, eigenfunctions

I have really enjoyed performing the method of separation of variables to identify the eigenfunctions and nodal lines (the set of points for which each eigenfunctions vanishes) of the 2-D wave equation $u_{tt}=c^2 \Delta u$ over circular and rectangular domains.

However, I really want to see what the nodal lines look like on other domains. Specifically, given a domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, I wish to approximate the nodal lines for the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\Delta u=\lambda u & (x,y)\in D\\ 
u=0 & (x,y)\in \partial D
\end{matrix}\right.$

I know that this is impossible for a general domain, so I first want to find a way of approximating these lines for a rectangle and a polygon (let's say a pentagon). I know we can obtain an analytical solution for the rectangle but the same cannot be said for other domains, which is why I seek a numerical technique.

The problem is that I really don't know where to start. I don't know whether I first need to approximate each eigenfunction before finding its zeros, or whether there is a way of identifying the nodal lines without knowing the eigenfunctions - perhaps by a symmetry argument.

There are many numerical methods out there but I don't know what would be best to solve this problem. Unfortunately, I have had no experience with numerical techniques and I fear that the level of mathematics is far beyond my capabilities.

However, I would really appreciate some advice on how to tackle this problem; I know it's not easy, but I would honestly appreciate any advice I can get before I continue my quest. If somebody could point me in the direction of an algorithm/method which will do the job, then that would be perfect.

Finally, I would like to apologise for the lack of clarity in my question. I am new to writing mathematics and I often find it difficult to convey my ideas in written form. Thus, if you do have any questions then please ask away.

Comment: I would suggest using finite element method to discretize the problem and then solve the resulting matrix eigenvalue problem of the form $Ax=b$. The type of problem you are describing is very well studied in mathematical literature. Finally you can post process nodal lines from the solutions of the algebraic eigenvalue problem. A benefit for using FEM is that you can use pretty much any domain $D$ that you can imagine. On the other hand, understanding finite elements can be a rather tedious task. I can give you an example of solving this problem in Matlab or Python if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you for your response knl. This sounds EXACTLY what I am searching for! I would love to see a Matlab example if it is at all possible? I cannot lie, that would be amazing. This method sounds well worth studying if it works on arbitrary two dimensional domains. I am very excited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uploaded [Matlab example to Github](https://gist.github.com/kinnala/a2878b50322d72d62eff). It requires PDE Toolbox and is quite rude but should work for any 2D domains that are supported by pdetool's *initmesh* function. I just plotted contours at solution equals zero to approximate nodal lines. You should create a better function for that job I presume.

[image: Example of eigenvector and nodal lines.]

Comment: Wow knl - that is amazing! I've just had a look at your code and it will probably take me a few days to understand what's going on in it, but the result is truly inspiring. This is honestly really great stuff. This example illustrates that what I want to do is possible, and so I am keen to take the time to understand your code. I do however, wish to read up on FEM, and try to grasp an understanding of how it works mathematically. Do you have any favourite literature that explains the basics on the maths behind FEM? Once again, thank you ever so much - you are a genius!

Comment: For beginning FE analysts with some mathematics background I usually recommend The Finite Element Method: Theory, Implementation and Applications by Larson and Bengzon. They choose clarity over rigor. For mathematical details you can then dig The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods by Brenner and Scott. Latter is not advised for a first read unless you are very serious and committed. Another good one is Finite elements by Braess. My impression is that this is somewhere between the first and the second book if you consider the required mathematical background.